# C++ template keyword in template definition

Tags: c++, templates, logging

I was reading the code from spdlog(C++ logging library) in github and i come up to the  following template:

```
template<typename Factory>
SPDLOG_INLINE std::shared_ptr<logger> stdout_color_mt(const std::string &logger_name, color_mode mode)
{
    return Factory::template create<sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>(logger_name, mode);
}
```

My general understanding of the code is that this will produce a function that will return a smart pointer using the another template called create. My confusion is about the meaning of Factory::template after the return statement.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `Factory` is a template type so `create` is a dependent name.  Since it is a template, you need that there to inform the compiler what it is.

Comment: Summarized, if you have a type `T` which has a template function `create<U>()` it's not sufficient to say `T::create<U>()`, you have to say `T::template create<U>()`.